# Result of GetHostEntry differs from nslookup

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, dns

**The problem**

I'm no windows expert so I'll try to be as exact as possible in order not to generate more confusion. I'm on a computer that is joined to a domain. That is, if I go to `Control Panel -> System and Security -> System` I see under `Computer name, domain, and workgroups settings` the following information:

```
Computer name: mycomputer
Full computer name: mycomputer.my.domain.tld
Computer description: ...
Domain: my.domain.tld
```

Now, I open a Powershell terminal and use the `ipconfig` command to get the IPv4 address of my computer, say 1.2.3.4, and then execute the following command

```
PS> [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("1.2.3.4")
```

where I get as answer that my computer is `mycomputer.my.domain.tld`. I then execute the following command

```
nslookup "1.2.3.4"
```

where I get as answer that my computer is `mycomputer.otherdomain.tld`. This is the correct reverse dns lookup entry of my computer.

**What I've tried**

So I thought that maybe the dns entry was cached. I opend a Powershell terminal as admin and executed `ipconfig /flushdns`. After that the `GetHostEntry` command is still showing that my computer is `mycomputer.my.domain.tld`.

I then logged into another windows computer that is located in the same subnet and executed again the command

```
PS> [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("1.2.3.4")
```

which returned `mycomputer.otherdomain.tld`. From that computer the command `nslookup "1.2.3.4"` also returns the correct result `mycomputer.otherdomain.tld`.

**Summary**

I don't understand what is happening here. The `GetHostEntry` command is returning the right answer when an ip address of other computer is given, but if the ip address of the local computer is given it returns the wrong reverse dns lookup result. Can someone explain me this behaviour?

**Update**

After using Wireshark to troubleshoot the issue saw the following behavior (I always clear the DNS cache with `ipconfig /flushdns` before each trial):

- `nslookup` always performs a reverse DNS request as expected
- `GetHostEntry` performs a reverse DNS request if I query an ip of other computer in the same subnet, say 1.2.3.5, and returns the right PTR entry, say `othercomputer.otherdomain.tld`
- `GetHostEntry` **does not** perform any reverse DNS request if I query the local ip 1.2.3.4

Comment: Are the DNS server listing and DNS Search Suffixes between the two machines different when you do an `ipconfig /all` on each box?

Comment: @trebleCode I'm not sure what you mean with DNS server listing. When I execute `ipconfig /all` I get under `DNS Suffix Search List` a list with four suffixes. Both computers have the same list but in different order. In the computer that I call `mycomputer` the suffix `otherdomain.tld` is first and `my.domain.tld` is third.

Comment: Guessing that is why the results are different. The computers are querying two different nameservers

Comment: DNS domain and AD domain are not the necessarily the same on a windows machine. Although it is not a desirable situation you can have a situation where a machine is member of an AD domain my.domain.tld but has a DNS domain configured (hard or by DHCP) like some.otherdomain.tld. This situation is called a disjoint namespace. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/disjoint-namespace. Although in some situations supported by Microsoft it is better to prevent such a situation.

Comment: @trebleCode yes, that hints to something. Anyway I still don't understand why is the DNS Suffix Search List relevant here. I read that the items in this list are added to "bare hostnames", like for example if I do a DNS query for `mycomputer` and not for a FQDN like `mycomputer.otherdomain.tld`. In my case I'm doing reverse DNS lookups of ip addresses and there is no sense in "suffixing" a domain to an ip address.

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld Thanks for the link. I guessed right that this kind of configuration is not standard.